# Visualforce Template with Custom Event Relationship

Tags: visualforce, approval-process, visualforce-template

I have a custom lookup field on Activities to Business_Trip__c, allowing linking multiple meetings to one trip and to the visited Accounts.
I want to create an VF approval template for the proposed trip which would include the related Events.

The code below works with

```
value="{!relatedTo.Events}">
```

But this is the standard event WhatId relationship - not appropriate for the Business_Trip__c object.
The Activity custom field lookup to Business_Trip__c tells me the Child Relationship is Meetings but the below code gets error:

```
Error: Invalid field Meetings for SObject Business_Trip__c
```

Please advise, thanks!

```
<p><b>Planned Meetings:</b></p>
<table border="1" >

    <apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Meetings}">
        <tr>
             <td>Name: {!cx.WhoId}</td>
             <td>Date: {!cx.ActivityDate}</td>
             <td>Company: {!cx.Whatid}</td>
             <td>Subject: {!cx.Subject}</td>

        </tr>

    </apex:repeat>                 
</table>
<p />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relationship needs to be expressed as:

```
<apex:repeat var="cx" value="{!relatedTo.Meetings__r}">
```